# Replacing characters in a string with X C++ exercise

Tags: c++, string

I was just doing some exercises and I got stuck on trying to change the characters of the string `s` to the character `x`, and this is my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
using std::vector;
using std::array;

int main()
{
    string s{ "Hello" };
    for (auto &c : s)
        char c{ "x" };
}
```

But it is throwing out the error:

> 'c': 'std::string' differs in levels of indirection from '_Elem &'    T

If anyone could help that would be great

Comment: Character literals use single quotes. You also want to loose the declaraction inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing your for loop with:

```
for(auto &c : s)
    c = 'x'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use an algorithm:

```
std::fill(begin(s), end(s), ‘X’);
```

In your code you use a string literal to initialize a `char`. You also don’t want to define a new `char` but assign to the reference you already got.

Answer (score 1):

Change the value of `c` will change the characters in `s`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
using std::vector;
using std::array;

int main()
{
    string s{ "Hello" };
    for (auto &c : s)
        c = 'x';
    cout << s;
}
```